# How to flush memory before a pci device reads memory in linux kernel

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, fpga, dma, pci-e

I have a pci device that reads memory allocated by dma_alloc_coherent

In the kernel documentation it says:
"You may however need to make sure to flush the processor's write buffers before telling devices to read that memory"

How exactly do i do that? how do i flush the memory so that the device reads correct data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use wmb() to make sure all the writes to memory completed before the write to the device telling it to start DMA.